# Input properties in angular directives

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm having a problem with input properties in angular directive used in my reactive form (Side question here: Is it a good practice to use directives in reactive forms?). I want to create universal directive for cross field validation that would take as an input two strings each for the name of a field to validate. Here's some code to illustrate what I mean.

```
// Directive
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appConfirmEqualValidator]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useClass: ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective,
            multi: true,
        }
    ],
})
export class ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective implements OnInit, Validator {

    @Input() confEqSecControlName: string // = 'password' ; would work if uncommented
    @Input() confEqFirstControlName: string //  = 'confirmPassword' ;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    validate(controlGroup: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
        console.log(this.confEqFirstControlName + ' ' + this.confEqSecControlName);

        let firstControl = controlGroup.get(this.confEqFirstControlName);
        let secControl = controlGroup.get(this.confEqSecControlName);

        console.log(firstControl.value + ' fc ' + secControl.value + ' sec');
        if (firstControl && secControl && ( firstControl.value !== secControl.value )) {
            return { 'notEqual': true};
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}


// HTML
<!-- Password Group -->
<div formGroupName="passwordGroup" appConfirmEqualValidator [confEqFirstControlName]="'password'" [confEqSecControlName]="'confirmPassword'">
    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="passwordId">Password</label>
        <div>
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="password" type="text" id="passwordId" placeholder="Password (required)" />
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwordGroup.password').errors">Danger</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Confirm Password -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="confirmPasswordId">Confirm Password</label>
        <div>
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="confirmPassword" type="text" id="confirmPasswordId" placeholder="Confirm Password (required)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="signUpForm.get('passwordGroup').errors?.notEqual">Not Equal</div>
</div>
```

[pastebin for clarity](https://pastebin.com/e0egPTUE)

I'm new to angular but from what I've read in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding) this should work just fine. Well It isn't. The values are not being bound to properties at all, and the console logs 'undefined'. Everything works just fine when I specify default values, but well then with hard-coded values I'd have to make one directive/function for each set of fields. I'd be very grateful for some help, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you are providing the directive to itself.

Comment: You mean the 'providers' property in @Directive decorator? From what I've learnt this is how you register your custom validator. Without it the validation doesn't work even with hard-coded values.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `Attribute` decorator instead to get those values? This blog seems to be using that: https://www.google.com/amp/s/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2